# Jobs are automatically deleted in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins

We are using Jenkins for continuous integration for our maven projects. We are using SVN as repository.

We have below configuration for our Jenkins jobs:

```
Build Triggers: Poll SCM (Schedule: * * * * *)
Source Code Management: Subversion
Discard Old Builds: true Max # of builds to keep: 3
```

We are facing issues related to automatic deletion of the jobs. We have seen this many times in our Jenkins environment.

What can be the reason behind automatic deletion of the jobs? Also, is there any way to see log history related to this incident?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration won't cause the deletion of jobs.It only discards old builds.
You can check the JENKINS_HOME/jobs folder to see if the job folder is still there.